# Pandas dates wrong when writing to drive

Tags: python, pandas

the following code messes up dates in pandas/python3 when writing an excel to the hard drive:

(actually, it doesn't, see edit and screenshot below)

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df = df.set_index('Date')
high = df['High'].resample("Y").max()
low = df['Low'].resample("Y").min()

# reverse order:
high = high.iloc[::-1]
low = low.iloc[::-1]
# join: 
joined = pd.concat([high, low], axis=1)

joined.to_excel("filename.xlsx")
```

Here's what df looks like before the code is run:

```
            Date       Open       High        Low      Close  Adj Close    Volume
0     2005-08-11   3.250000   3.310000   3.200000   3.240000   2.459549  76671500
1     2005-08-12   3.250000   3.600000   3.250000   3.586000   2.722203  29113500
2     2005-08-15   3.550000   3.570000   3.452000   3.460000   2.626554  10596500
3     2005-08-16   3.380000   3.460000   3.380000   3.430000   2.603780   5141000
4     2005-08-17   3.430000   3.440000   3.360000   3.370000   2.558233   6423500
...          ...        ...        ...        ...        ...        ...       ...
3847  2020-11-20  32.320000  33.669998  32.220001  33.500000  33.500000   2933400
3848  2020-11-23  34.029999  36.090000  34.029999  35.820000  35.820000   4581300
3849  2020-11-24  36.230000  38.770000  36.230000  38.650002  38.650002   6318500
3850  2020-11-25  38.240002  38.709999  37.320000  38.169998  38.169998   3442500
3851  2020-11-27  38.560001  39.410000  38.279999  38.770000  38.770000   2427000
```

If I `print(joined)`, I see

```
                 High        Low
Date                            
2020-12-31  48.189999  19.730000
2019-12-31  55.150002  38.900002
2018-12-31  56.509998  35.700001
2017-12-31  43.419998  25.040001
2016-12-31  40.950001  20.770000
2015-12-31  70.320000  39.639999
2014-12-31  58.057999  44.023998
2013-12-31  47.880001  33.866001
2012-12-31  45.598000  29.916000
2011-12-31  38.540001  23.068001
2010-12-31  27.747999  11.512000
2009-12-31  19.025999   8.460000
2008-12-31  34.598000   7.542000
2007-12-31  23.775999   5.140000
2006-12-31   5.320000   2.582000
2005-12-31   3.600000   2.238000
```

on my command line.

Writing to excel using `joined.to_excel("filename.xlsx")` results in the following output:

```
                 High        Low
Date                            
2021-12-36  48.189999  19.730000
2020-12-36  55.150002  38.900002 (rest skipped)
```

Clearly, the dates don't match up. Is my code faulty, if so I'd appreciate a fix/help? Maybe its a bug in pandas too, I don't know. Interestingly, using `dataframe.to_csv()` instead works without messing up the dates. It writes the same data as it prints. Strange!

## Edit:

This was no pandas issue, it turns out it's macOS that's misbehaving and displaying the preview of excel files wrong:
[image]

If I instead load the file into excel, all's good.

Comment: can you show what is the dataframe before? how does `df` and `df["date"]` looks like?

Comment: I've edited the original post to include df going in.

Comment: Enlarge the width of the date column in the Excelsheet when looking at it.

Comment: this works fine. The output is as expected in excel. or you can try to convert the `Date` to string by `joined["Date"] = joined["Date"].astype(str)` and export it to excel.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments! I use a Mac and the messed up stuff appears when I use the spacebar in finder to view the files. I do that a lot. Something about how Catalina handles excel files I guess. Opening the file into excel displays the dates properly. So no python issue, rather a macOS issue!

Comment: if the problem is resolved, then please close the question.

Comment: Joe, I've posted an answer to this in the hope that it closes the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the edit for an answer to posted issue.